# Use double integrals to find the volume under the surface $z = 1/(y+2)$, and over the area bounded by $y = x$ and $y^2 + x = 2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Use double integrals to find the volume under the surface $z = 1/(y+2)$, and over the area bounded by $y = x$ and $y^2 + x = 2$

I found $$\int_{-2}^{1} \int_{\sqrt{2-x}}^{x} \frac{1}{y+2}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x$$ and this was solved to $\frac{7}{2}$, however the book answers show that the actual answer is $\frac{9}{2}$. Not really sure where I've gone wrong here, there isn't any indication that the solid is also bounded by the axes (could these additional bounds be implied?). \

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt {2-x} <y<x$ is not possible when $x <0$.

Comment: Always plot a graph for these problems; it will then be easier to determine the integration limits appropriately. Additionally, consider whether the order of integration, either $dxdy$ or $dydx$, is more suitable according to the regions.

Answer (score 1):

Integral should look like:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-2}^1\int_{y}^{-y^2+2}\frac{1}{y+2}dxdy &= \int_{-2}^1\frac{1}{y+2}\left(\int_{y}^{-y^2+2}dx\right)dy.
\end{aligned}
$$

Then, the answer is $\frac{9}{2}$.